# Usar a mesma entidade no Hibernate para gravar em duas tabelas

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou usando o Hibernate para fazer a persistência no banco de dados, e em um determinado caso, para cada atualização que uma determinada entidade `Consultor` tiver, ela deverá atualizar na tabela principal chamada de `TB_Consultor`e inserir uma nova linha na tabela `TB_ConsultorHistorico`.

A estrutura das tabelas `TB_Consultor` e `TB_ConsultorHistorico` são idênticas, e desse modo, 
o que eu estou evitando é ter que mapear uma entidade `Consultor` e outra `ConsultorHistorico` que serão idênticas, e fazer tudo com uma entidade só.

É possível mapear com o Hibernate para a mesma entidade gravar em duas tabelas no banco? Sendo que em uma haverá inserções e atualizações, e na outra, só inserções.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Herança com mapeamento via anotações

Esta é uma pergunta muito comum e a maioria das vezes indica-se usar uma bordagem baseada na herança. Por exemplo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations) nos dá base para o seguinte exemplo:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class ConsultorBase { /* código da classe vai aqui */ }

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_Consultor")
public class Consultor extends ConsultorBase { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_ConsultorHistorico")
public class ConsultorHistorico extends ConsultorBase { ... }
```

## Mapeamento via XML

Em outras respostas ([esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997950/map-two-identical-tables-same-schema-to-same-entity-in-hibernate) e [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215471/how-to-map-2-identical-tables-same-properties-to-1-entity)) sugere-se usar um arquivo XML separado para mapear a entidade. Dessa forma você não precisa de uma *superclasse*.

Exemplo de mapeamento:

```xml
<class name="Consultor" table="TB_Consultor"
        entity-name="Consultor">
    ...
</class>

<class name="Consultor" table="TB_ConsultorHistorico"
        entity-name="ConsultorHistorico">
    ...
</class>
```

Então, dependendo do tipo de entidade que você precisa, você chama os métodos apropriados da sessão, como o método [save](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```java
session.save("Consultor", consultor);
```

Ou:

```java
session.save("ConsultorHistorico", Historico);
```

A [documentação oficial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-entityname), que inspirou o exemplo acima, diz que para fazer a desambiguação, precisamos usar o `entity name`, tanto no XML quanto no parâmetro.

---

<sup>Esta resposta foi baseada (porém bem adaptada) da original do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755260/hibernate-two-tables-per-one-entity).</sup>

Comment: Obrigado, tive que fazer algumas adaptações com @AttributeOverride pois as tabelas não eram 100% iguais, pois em uma o ID era chave primária, e na outra não, mas no fim deu certo.